# What exactly is Jungo WinDriver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Haven't seen this thing before, in 5+ years of running Windows 7 on Dell laptops. What is it?

[image: Device Manager]

I found a [post allegedly from a Jungo employee](http://forums.anandtech.com/showpost.php?s=8f299f66ea5914b491a571686694ee45&p=36982441&postcount=9), but still have no idea how that bloatware ended up on my system.

Comment: What do you do? The site says it is used to develop drivers for USB/PCI devices: http://www.jungo.com/st/products/windriver/

Comment: I do [web development](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu?tab=tags). Nothing having to do with drivers.

Comment: I see. I found the original forum post you linked a part of. They suggest you uninstall it and see if any USB/PCI device stops working. Perhaps it was bundled with other drivers or some software.

Answer (score 1):

Jungo WinDriver is used to communicate with USB and PCI devices. Many companies use Jungo for their hardware so it's impossible to tell how it ended up on your system.

Consult their website for more information.
http://www.jungo.com/st/products/windriver/

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Jungo is installed when Vernier Logger Pro® is installed. Completely harmless. I believe it is used for communicating with scientific usb data loggers. It's a generic, reliable library so Vernier does not have to start off from scratch.

> The WinDriver™ device driver development tool supports any device, regardless of its silicon vendor, and enables you to focus on your driver’s added-value functionality, instead of on the operating system internals. WinDriver’s driver development solution covers USB, PCI and PCI Express

https://www.jungo.com/st/products/windriver/

https://www.vernier.com/til/2582/

Comment: Sounds somewhat like libusb.

Comment: The "completely harmless" bit might be true if there were no [exploits](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-16972/product_id-40210/Jungo-Windriver.html).

Comment: @EdwardBrey Great point, it does increase attack surface but the software itself is not malicious